# .htaccess RewriteRule - Difference between [L,R] and [R,L]?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there any difference between flag [L,R] and [R,L] e.g:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

vs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No there is no difference in 2 rules.

Order of various flags in `RewriteRule` doesn't matter.

**Reference:** [httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)